# Why do I have a Runtime Error in finding Longest Common Prefix among a list of strings?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

**Question:**

Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

My code passes the test case but when I submit I get a runtime error saying that `firstWord` is not iterable. What am I doing wrong?

```
let longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  let result = '';
  let firstWord = strs[0];
  let index = 0;

  for (let letter of firstWord) {
    for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
      let comparisonWord = strs[i];
      var comparisonLetter = comparisonWord[index];
      if (comparisonLetter !== letter) {
        return result;
      }
    }
    index++;
    result += comparisonLetter;
  }
  return result;
};
```

Comment: Which value for `strs` does the function receive when you have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the **length of strs is 0**, then there will be **no firstword to iterate**.

if the **length of strs is 1**, then the **result will be the only string present** in strs.

```
  var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
        
      if(strs.length == 0)
          return "";
      
      if(strs.length == 1)
          return strs[0];
        
      let result = '';
      let firstWord = strs[0];
      let index = 0;
    
      for (let letter of firstWord) {
        for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
          let comparisonWord = strs[i];
          var comparisonLetter = comparisonWord[index];
          if (comparisonLetter !== letter) {
            return result;
          }
        }
        index++;
        result += comparisonLetter;
      }
      return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

whe the length of strs is 0, str[0] equal undefined, so not iterate

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  if(strs.length === 0) {
    return "";
  }

  let pre = "";
  let result = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < strs[0].length; i++) {
    pre = strs[0].slice(0, i+1)

    const filters = strs.filter(item => {
        return item.slice(0, i+1) === pre;
    });

    if (filters.length === strs.length) {
      result = pre;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to simplify things Ive made it in a functional way.
Also, explicit transform to array could help `[...str]`.

```
function longestCommonPrefixOfPair(strA, strB) {
  if (strA.length === 0 || strB.length === 0) return '';
  if (strA.length > strB.length) return longestCommonPrefix(strB, strA);

  const pairs = toChars(strA).map((a, i) => [a, strB[i]]);
  const prefixLength = pairs.findIndex(([a, b]) => a !== b);
  return prefixLength >= 0 ? strA.slice(0, prefixLength) : strA;
}

function toChars(str) {
  return [...str];
}

const longestCommonPrefix = (strs) => strs.reduce(longestCommonPrefixOfPair);

console.log(["123456", "12345", "123456789", "123"].reduce(longestCommonPrefix)); // 123
```